# Where can I find the Titanfall screenshots folder?

Tags: origin, titanfall

I took some screenshots using F10 in Titanfall. Where can I find the folder that contains my screenshots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.

`C:/Program Files x86/Origin Games/Titanfall/r1/screenshots/`

If you installed Titanfall into a different folder, you'll need to amend this path. For example your Origin folder is on your `D:` drive.

`D:/Origin/Titanfall/r1/screenshots/`

Comment: In my case the path was slightly different:  `<origin games folder>\Titanfall\r1_dlc1\screenshots`
(Even though I don't have any DLCs...  The universe is a mysterious place)

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your screenshots at:

```
C:/Origin/Titanfall/r1_dlc1/screenshots/
```

Replacing `C:` with the drive Origin is installed in.